# How to find /mysite/ folder - SilverStripe CMS

Tags: silverstripe

I'm having some trouble finding my /mysite/ folder - I'm trying to edit my _config.php file so I can add some schema to a website however, there is no /mysite/ folder. Is it possible it was renamed something else, or simply doesn't exist? Is there a way I can find out which folder is the "/mysite/" folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be in your webroot, where also a */framework/* and a */cms/* folder should be. Look at the webserver configuration to find out where the root of your website is located.

How did you install silverstripe? Did you use composer? Did you download a ready-to-use zip? If yes, which one?

Comment: I didn't install SilverStripe - another developer installed it. I am in the webroot where the /framework/ and /cms/ folder are but there is no /mysite/ folder.

Comment: @mako, That folder can have any name, is not a requirement to be name _mysite_. You can put all the names of folders here, but that will make the question too localized (if it isn't already....). There's no docs for it? Maybe he change it to "app" or "site"... imposible to know without looking though.

Comment: Exactly - waiting to hear back from the developer who set it up but I'm pretty sure he changed it to app, so that pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

The global variable `$project` is defined with the name of the "mysite" folder (it's basically the project folder).

So echoing that out from `ContentController::init()` would be a good way to determine it. Otherwise, just search the folders for "Page_Controller" and you should find the page class and where all the other work is stored.

```
global $project;
var_dump($project);
die;
```